# Creating independent module for interface

Tags: biztalk

Is it possible to create independent module for all interface that is connected to the biztalk application We are connecting 19 different systems to the biztalk serer so the future enhancement should not cause any effect on the whole application the changes must be reflected in particular interface 
say if I have interfaces like dialler,posidex, mlms ,Mfos ,finnonelms
If I have to modify only posidex the change must only be reflected in that and not in all the interface
How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to employ a publication-subscription infrastructure.

Each interface of a common solution should map to a canonical interface (schema) on the publication side. Then this canonical schema is what you use on the publication side. The advantage of this, is that when you pub interface changes you only have to update and deploy the pub project and how it maps to the canonical schema.

Effectively you will have something like 3+ Visual Studio projects, a pub, canonical, and one to many sub. The sub and the pub will both reference the canonical, which contains the common artifacts. You will deploy all the projects to the same BizTalk app. In the future if you pub interface changes you can alter it, and deploy it without having to worry about how it will effect your subscribers.